# Saving mapview (leaflet) maps with embedded popupGraph()s

Tags: r, save, leaflet

Using R, I like the wonderful `mapview` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapview/), which adds some features on top of the standard `leaflet`.

I have a `mapview()` object which I'd like to save to disk to be able to open it later. This object contains `popupGraph()` popups, which are basically embedded `.png`s.

Prepare data (taken from the mapview online examples, you can see them, and the results, [here](http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/popups/html/popups.html)):

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)
library(lattice)
pnt <- data.frame(x = 174.764474, y = -36.877245)
coordinates(pnt) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(pnt) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
p2 <- levelplot(t(volcano), col.regions = terrain.colors(100))
mv <- mapview(pnt, popup = popupGraph(p2, width = 300, height = 300))
```

I can use `mapshot()` to save to `.html`:

```
mapshot(mv, url = paste0(getwd(), "/map.html"))
```

But I get this error:

```
pandoc: Could not find data file map_files/leaflet-0.7.7/
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97
```

So I can try with `save()`:

save(mv, file="map.Rdata")

Which works. Once I restart R and reload the data with `load()`, however, the graphed image embedded in the plot is not there anymore:

[image]

This is because the image points to:
`/tmp/RtmpVGHIwH/graphs/tmp_1.png`

Which of course is not present anymore since I restarted R.

How can I save, together with the `mapview()` object, also the embedded images?

Comment: The `pandoc` error you see should be resolved with the latest development version of the package. 
`devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg@develop"`
This will, however, not fix the problem of saving popupGraphs to disk. I will need to look into this. I'll get back to you as soon as I have a suitable solution.

Comment: Can you please try the latest develop version. This should work now, but be aware that whenever you move the folder where you saved your .html, you will also need to move a folder called `popup_graphs` one folder level above. Regard this as a temporary fix, I hope that we can get this implemented in a better way, but for that I need the **leaflet** folk to cooperate.

Comment: @TimSalabim I'll try this asap and report back. Thanks.